# Differential equations: Romeo and Juliet/ Locksley Hall

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to make an assignment on differential equations and Romeo and Juliet.

$r(t)$ is romeo's love for Juliet at time $t$, $j(t)$ is Juliet's love for Romeo at time $t$

So far, it is given: $\frac{dr}{dt}=-j$ and $\frac{dj}{dt}=r$.

It is also given that Romeo & Juliet's families are enemies, thus the initial condition at time $t=0$ is $(r,j)=(-1,-1)$

If we would take the second derivative of $r$ we get: $r''=-j'$. We know that $j'=r$, which means $r''=-r$.  can be recognized as the equation of an harmonic oscillator. Our solution will therefore have this shape: $r=A \sin(t)+B \cos(t)$.

To get the solution to $j$, we know $j=-r'$, which gives us:

$Rj= -(A\cos(t)-B\sin(t))= -A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)R$

With the initial conditions:

$r(t)= \sin(t)-\cos(t)$ and $j(t)=-\cos(t)-\sin(t)$

Now, the last part of the assignment is:

“In the Spring a young man’s fancy lightly turns to thoughts of love,” says Tennyson. 
**What differential equation concept is best invoked to capture this
idea?**

A. a forcing term

B. an unstable equilibrium

C. a nonlinear function for $t$

D. none of the above

Could someone help me with this part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of writing the equations bold :)

Answer (score 1):

"Spring" is a **time** of the year.  So the best answer is (C), the only one that references t.

Comment: A forcing term certainly depends on $t$ too (and I think that's the intended answer).